# Select product's with the most occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: I have the following table in mysql]

I want which product_id has been purchased the most for a particular month say aug.
So, the query  should return product ids and the no of times it has been purchased.I am getting stuck because of the two different product id has been purchased the same no of times, then what will be solution?
I have tried this,

```
select Product_Id, count(Product_Id) repeater   
from mydatabase.dateofpurchase  
where month(dateofpurchase) = 8
group by Product_Id
having count(Product_Id) > 1  
order by repeater desc ;
```

This Query is returning all the ids and their repetition times. I want only those id's that are maximum times purchased. If it is one then it returns one and if two it returns two.

Comment: Does your 'dateofpurchase' table not have a Primary Key or unique index?

Comment: how do you define maximum ? I mean what does this mean *If it is one then it returns one and if two it returns two.*

Comment: you may be able to use select top 1 depending on database.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support TOP @Danimal

Comment: So if two products have same count which one you want?

Comment: @raymond, you're right i did not see the mysql initially, Limit would be the command.

Comment: @ChrisJ yes it has which is auto incremented and created at random.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza this is the problem...first it will check: if only one id is having highest count, then it should return only that id..but  if two products have the same count then i want all of them but their count should still remain maximum..if only one product has the highest count then I want that product only. also i can't limit because it will give the first result only..

Comment: That would be easy with CTE (MySQL 8 and MariaDB 10.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what is the max `repeater` , and join it to your original query :

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM(select Product_Id, count(Product_Id) repeater   
     from mydatabase.dateofpurchase  
     where month(dateofpurchase) = 8
     group by Product_Id) s
JOIN(select count(product_id) as max_repeater
     FROM mydatabase.dateofpurchase  
     where month(dateofpurchase) = 8
     group by Product_Id
     order by max_repeater DESC
     LIMIT 1) t
 ON(t.max_repeater = s.repeater)
```

Comment: `t.max_repeater = s.repeater`  ??

Comment: @sagi working fine..thank you so much..I am getting expected.. :)

Comment: @sagi .also tell me how to appreciate your work. I am new to stack overflow.

Comment: No problem man. You can upvote the answer (the ^ mark next to it) and you can approve it (The V mark below the upvote mark) @HardeepSinghNegi

Answer (score 1):

```
select Product_Id, count(Product_Id) repeater   
from mydatabase.dateofpurchase  
where month(dateofpurchase) = 8
group by Product_Id
having count(Product_Id) =select max(x) 
                          from (select count(Product_Id) as x    
                                from mydatabase.dateofpurchase  
                                where month(dateofpurchase) = 8
                                group by Product_Id) b
order by repeater desc ;
```

Comment: Aggregation function on an aggregation function , is that possible ?

Comment: check @sagi answer. You could use `ORDER and LIMIT 1` instead `MAX(x)`